# How to concatenate inside a link?

Tags: html, blogger

I'm building a blog using Blogger, and I'm trying to create my own share buttons, using a simple image linking. I have the page's url, which is:

```
"data:post.url"
```

I want to insert the page's url into the Facebook share url, which is "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=", in a way that the page's url would come right after the share url. 
So far, I've tried some ways to do so, none given the proper outcome.
This is where I want to insert the urls:

```
<a class='addthis_button_facebook'>
  <a href='DESIRED COMLETE URL'>
    <img alt='Share to Facebook' border='0' height='30' src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8ZBAqJOFFw0/WHdENG3DINI/AAAAAAAAARA/jabYU0WscU0zwW7I_HwsF0NWkdPI2NkwACEw/w140-h140-p/1484232837_2_-_Facebook.png' width='30'/>
  </a>
</a>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `expr:` with `href` attribute to get data from blogger

```
<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img alt='Share to Facebook' border='0' height='30' src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8ZBAqJOFFw0/WHdENG3DINI/AAAAAAAAARA/jabYU0WscU0zwW7I_HwsF0NWkdPI2NkwACEw/w140-h140-p/1484232837_2_-_Facebook.png' width='30'/></a>
```

Another note: Why using two anchor elements, one enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I tried it and the result link is without the post url- only this: "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=". It avoids the "data:post.url". I'd like to hear what to do, thanks!

Comment: It works only inside blog posts widget. Send your code.